# Cannot create larger partitions with APFS filesystem

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, apfs

I am trying to use Boot Camp Assistant to create a partition for Windows that is 100 GB. However, I am unable to create a partition of that size.

Trying to create a 100 GB FAT32 partition (via the command `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 400G FAT32 BOOTCAMP 100G`) from Terminal results in the following error, starting from the result of the automatic `fsck_apfs` that is done:

```
The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Shrinking APFS Physical Store disk0s2 from 500,068,036,608 to 400,000,000,000 bytes
Shrinking APFS data structures
APFS Container Resize error code is 49187
Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures
```

The output of `diskutil list` returns the following:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Main                    282.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 20.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                519.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      12.9 GB    disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *64.2 GB    disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WININSTALL              64.2 GB    disk2s1
```

As for the `diskutil apfs list` output:

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 F8CFD798-0C08-45AE-8F6D-FAAC9650F2A2
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      500068036608 B (500.1 GB)
    Minimum Size:                 301437767680 B (301.4 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   292004704256 B (292.0 GB) (58.4% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       208063332352 B (208.1 GB) (41.6% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 DEE143FB-B604-4F51-9BB7-C358B01D5137
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       500068036608 B (500.1 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 CFBE30B9-AE09-39D3-9F19-CF4EB5A08611
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Main (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         282714124288 B (282.7 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 51246A8F-B84B-401C-9896-5D7CD4F4D621
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         20156416 B (20.2 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 9F0127AA-3C09-49E0-A3E7-A0487C781E5E
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         518995968 B (519.0 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 10062AED-5DC0-4764-86A3-8F9745027C51
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
        Capacity Consumed:         8589983744 B (8.6 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

Finally, for `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits`:

```
Resize limits for APFS Physical Store partition disk0s2:
  Current Physical Store partition size on map:   500.1 GB (500068036608 Bytes)
  Minimum (constrained by files/snapshots):       308.7 GB (308658987008 Bytes)
  Recommended minimum (if used with macOS):       319.4 GB (319396405248 Bytes)
  Maximum (constrained by partition map space):   500.1 GB (500068036608 Bytes)
```

I should have about 200 GB free within `disk1`, so the amount of space I have remaining should not be a problem.

FileVault is not on, as evidenced by the output of `diskutil apfs list`.

I have also disabled Time Machine via `tmutil disable`, have disconnected any backup disks in System Preferences, disabled "Back Up Automatically", and have deleted all local snapshots via `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 99999999999999`. Running `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` returns nothing, not even an empty line.

I have booted to single user mode, and have run `fsck_apfs -d -l disk0` myself (along with the same command for disk1). It (along with First Aid) says the disk is OK.

I have reinstalled macOS completely.

However, despite all my problems, I am able to produce a 40 GB partition (via `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 460 FAT32 BOOTCAMP 40G`):

```
The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Shrinking APFS Physical Store disk0s2 from 500,068,036,608 to 459,999,997,952 bytes
Shrinking APFS data structures
Shrinking partition
Modifying partition map
4096 bytes per physical sector
/dev/rdisk0s3: 78103872 sectors in 1220373 FAT32 clusters (32768 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=64 res=32 nft=2 mid=0xf8 spt=32 hds=255 hid=898848768 drv=0x80 bsec=78123008 bspf=9536 rdcl=2 infs=1 bkbs=6
Mounting disk
1 new disk created or changed due to APFS operation
Disk from APFS operation: disk0s3
Finished APFS operation
```

Is this ultimately a problem of not having enough free space (despite things saying otherwise)? I could attempt removing files to free another 60 GB and see if I can then create a partition with 100 GB of space.

Would appreciate a fix to this problem that avoids having to reformat the drive, however if that is the only solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are entering the command incorrectly. Below is what you entered.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 400G FAT32 BOOTCAMP 100G
```

What you should have entered is given below.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 400G FAT32 BOOTCAMP 0
```

Basically, you should let the command determine the size of the `BOOTCAMP` partition.

If you can not get a 100GB `BOOTCAMP` partition after reinstalling macOS completely, then how about creating the partition before reinstalling. In other words, enter the command below to **destroy** everything and create the correct partitioning before reinstalling macOS.

```
sudo diskutil partitiondisk disk0 2 gpt apfs Main 400G fat32 BOOTCAMP R
```

Again, the above command will determine the size of the `BOOTCAMP` partition.

One final note:

It appears you are trying to install Windows without a Recovery partition. If so, the the recovery files will be placed inside of the `BOOTCAMP` partition. This is not how Windows is normally installed for an EFI boot. Also, you have not allocated a System Reserved partition. Although, the Boot Camp Assistant does not allocate for a System Reserved partition either and Windows seems to operate correctly on Macs without one.

Comment: Great analysis. This OP really has a non-standard layout which clearly will cause a lot of problems. Nice job here both in the details asking, Vangekis and the answer David.